# $taglibLiferay.language("fm", null, "languageId",3)

Tags: liferay-6

Can anyone explain the Use of

```
$taglibLiferay.language("fm", null, "languageId",3)
```

in `liferay` Theme portal_normal.vm file.

I have used it in Theme for changing the language.

Answer (score 0):

This is usage of language portlet allowing to displays all available languages.

```
$taglibLiferay.language(String formName, String formAction, String name, String[] languageIds, int displayStyle)
```